# How do I return a value from two CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a piece of Java code with two `CompletableFuture`s, like so:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
        doThing1(withThis));

CompletableFuture<Boolean> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
        doThing2(withThat));
```

I want to race these two `CompletableFuture`s and take the first resulting Boolean and store it in a variable. However, I would also like to ensure that neither future runs for longer than 60 seconds (although this is unnecessary). I then want to ensure that both of these `CompletableFuture`s are killed, and my program resumes on just the main thread.

How could I pull this off simply and reliably? Or, am I using the wrong tools for the job at hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`CompletableFuture.anyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#anyOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-). And then call `get` to await execution.

```
CompletableFuture<Object> future3 = CompletableFuture.anyOf(future1, future2);
Boolean result = (Boolean) futur3.get();
return result;
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture#cancel` doesn't have access to any potential underlying actions. It's more or less a noop.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Looking at the source, it doesn't interrupt any threads. [I wouldn't say it's a noop though](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.2.1/java8/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#CompletableFuture.cancel%28boolean%29), just in this case, when there's no dependent CompletableFutures.